# Sorting and grouping rows according to timestamps in different columns

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a table that looks like this

```
ID Event_A Event_B Event_C
1   01-01
1   01-02 
1           01-05
2   01-02
2                   01-03
3   01-03
3   01-04
3           01-06
3                   01-08
```

And I need an output like this

```
ID Event_1 Event_2 Event_3 Event_4
1   A       A       B
2   A       C
3   A       A       B       C
```

So basically have one row for each ID and all the event types in columns according to their timestamps (chronological order).

Can anyone advise how the macro should look like OR sql query to turn the original table around?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA routine to reformat your data:

1. Assumes source data is in active sheet, starting at `A1`
2. Places result on active sheet starting at `F1` - adjust to suit your needs

---

```
Sub SummariseList()
    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim rDst As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim vDst() As Variant
    Dim srcCol As Long, srcRow As Long
    Dim dstCol As Long, dstRow As Long
    Dim ID As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set rSrc = Range([A1].End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0), [A2].End(xlDown))
    vSrc = rSrc

    Set rDst = [F2]

    ' Count IDs and events '
    dstRow = 1
    dstCol = 1
    i = 1
    For srcRow = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
        If vSrc(srcRow, 1) = vSrc(srcRow - 1, 1) Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            dstRow = dstRow + 1
            If dstCol < i Then dstCol = i
            i = 1
        End If
    Next

    If dstCol < i Then dstCol = i
    ReDim vDst(1 To dstRow, 1 To dstCol + 1)

    ' Output table labels '
    rDst.Offset(-1, 0) = "ID"
    For i = 1 To dstCol
        rDst.Offset(-1, i) = "Event_" & i
    Next

    ' Create output data '  
    ID = vSrc(1, 1)
    vDst(1, 1) = ID
    dstRow = 1
    dstCol = 2
    For srcRow = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
        If vSrc(srcRow, 1) <> ID Then
            ' update vDst '  
            ID = vSrc(srcRow, 1)
            dstCol = 2
            dstRow = dstRow + 1
            vDst(dstRow, 1) = ID
        End If
        For srcCol = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
            If vSrc(srcRow, srcCol) <> "" Then
                vDst(dstRow, dstCol) = Chr(srcCol + 63)
                dstCol = dstCol + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' Place result on sheet '
    rDst.Resize(dstRow, dstCol - 1) = vDst

End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason I get 'Type mismatch' error for running this macro.

Comment: On which line?  One possibility, if your ID's arn't numeric, use `Dim ID as Variant` instead of `Long`